# Android studio failed to resolve: core , activity , fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I started a new java project in android studio and after a few seconds Gradle finishes the build and it shows 3 errors:

- ERROR: Failed to resolve: core 
   Affected Modules: app
- ERROR: Failed to resolve: activity 
   Affected Modules: app
- ERROR: Failed to resolve: fragment 
   Affected Modules: app

What should I do to fix this?
[image: my errors and adanroid studio]

Comment: have you tried to create a new project and see whats the error. Because I think you broke some part of the project or your gradle is not updated!

Comment: yes, I updated gradle and my problem was solved. ;)

Comment: upvote my comment!

Comment: how can I upvote?

Comment: There is a triangular arrow before my answer (above the flag0!

Comment: No, there is nothing, You wrote a comment, not an answer, I think this is only for those who write the solution in the answer field.

Comment: No it is there but any ways leave it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your `gradle` verison see this [gradle version with plugins](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)